# HTML: show movement when tabbing between inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, keyboard, accessibility

I have a web app I would like to be controllable from the keyboard.

I recently saw a library that showed movement of the blue outline when tabbing between form fields. Eg, starting with the field 'one' highlighted:

```
[one]

another
```

Then when tab is hit:

```
one
[   ]
another
```

then finishing:

```
one

[another]
```

As you can see, it where the focus is moving to quite obvious for keyboard users.

The bad news: I can't find this library more, or anything like it. So my question:

**Is there a tool to show movement during field focus changes like this?** and, more to the point, where is it?

**EDIT**: Be a little more explicit: no, I really do not want make newly selected fields have an animated border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is called [Focus Transition](http://n12v.com/focus-transition), and the library is called [Flying Focus](https://github.com/NV/flying-focus).

Comment: Yes! If you change your answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I've added link to the answer's body

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not very hard effect (depends on conditions, of course), if i understand you correct.

Just create a 'dummy' hidden outline object in css and attach handler on focus event to all inputs you need and move your outline as you want in attached handler

For example with jQuery (written right here, may not work):

```
var $outline = $('#outline');
var padding = 6;

$('input').focus(function () {  
    var width = parseInt($(this).width()) + padding;
    var height = parseInt($(this).height()) + padding;
    var top = $(this).parent().offset()['top'] - padding/2;
    var left = $(this).parent().offset()['left'] - padding/2;
    $outline.stop().animate({
        top: top,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        left: left
    });
});
```

You can try this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/C4Gde/) with something similar